# Diophantine trouble

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

How can I now solve $x^2+y^2=x+y+2$?

I could not do anything  because 
$$x^2-x+y^2-y=2\Rightarrow x(x-1)+y(y-1)=2$$
And that is where I am stuck!!

Answer (score 4):

Hint. Your equation is equivalent to
$$(2x-1)^2+(2y-1)^2=10$$
where $10=(\pm 1)^2+(\pm 3)^2$.

Comment: Thanks a lot sir ,you saved me.